# How to insert an existing GUID into Oracle RAW(16) field in a script

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have an sql server script which inserts known fixed guid values into a table. It looks like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID)
VALUES ('BBD098BF-58F0-4A84-90C2-F806D6D06061')
```

Note that guid is in human-readable form.
Since ID is uniqueidentifier sql server understands how to convert a string to guid data type.

I need to make the same script for Oracle, ID is of RAW(16) type. Taking the script directly doesn't work because Oracle interprets a string just like a binary, it should be some "other" string, a string representation of a correct binary chunk.

Does anyone knows a way to convert human-readable sql server string to a string required by Oracle?

So far I can only think about saving a guid to Oracle in .net code, for example, and than making a select in oracle script to get a string. But this is crazy.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `HEXTORAW('BBD098BF-58F0-4A84-90C2-F806D6D06061' )` but I'm not sure I understand what you want

Comment: I have some records with fixed known guids in sql database but my project must support both sql server and oracle. The guids in sql server database and in Oracle must be the same. So that the same .net code could retrieve a record from each of the databases. My guess is that HEXTORAW would treat the string as a straightforward binary and the guids in two databases would be different.

Comment: @ElDog: hextoraw() should work just fine if you remove the `-` before calling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=196433)
Sqlserver reverses the 3 first sections so you need to do:

```
hextoraw(substr(guid,7,2)||
         substr(guid,5,2)||
         substr(guid,3,2)||
         substr(guid,1,2)||
         substr(guid,12,2)||
         substr(guid,10,2)||
         substr(guid,17,2)||
         substr(guid,15,2)||
         substr(guid,20,4)||
         substr(guid,25,12)
)
```

(guid is like 'BBD098BF-58F0-4A84-90C2-F806D6D06061')

Comment: Just curios: what is all that switching needed and not just call **hextoraw(replace(guid,'-',''))**?